# How can i detect when a <select> is clicked in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

i'm trying to detect when a select is clicked on a webview in android. After this, i'd also need to detect when a value on the select is chosen.

I have been trying to use  [*evaluateJavascript*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)), but i can't figure out how to make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I know only this method: the Android WebView sends to the server a header named `X-Requested-With`, the value of this header is the application's namespace (e.g. `com.example.myapp`).

Also, I think the developer of the app can remove this header. I'm not an Android Developer, you should take my last statement with a grain of salt.